# allow [0-9] numbers, p and %s in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

Example: `12`, `2p`, `2%s` -  these input values need to allow.

I am using this regex `[/^([0-9\.]|[p|%s])*$/]` and it allows `%s`,`s`,`p` and `%p` as well.

I tried with `[/^[0-9]*%s$]` which works fine regex tester, not working in my code. is there anything i need to make change in the regex to work in react.

1) It allows user to type multiple decimals `2.2.2.2`

2) Can able to type multiple `p`,`s`, `%`

How to avoid typing the above scenarios.

Edit: This regex [/^\d+(?:.\d+)?(?:p|%s)?$/] working fine when i test but when implement in code not allowing me to enter %s and decimal value

here is my code

```
 onValueChange(event: any) {

   const re=/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:p|%s)?$/
         if (event.target.value === '' || re.some(regEx => event.target.value.search(regEx) > -1)) {
    this.setState({ tempValue: event.target.value } as Ipreservice);
}

if (inputValue.indexOf(p) >= 0) {
        tempValue = inputValue.replace(new RegExp(p, 'g'), '');
displayUnit = DisplayUnit.p;
        }else if (inputValue.indexOf(%s) >= 0){
      tempValue = inputValue.replace(new RegExp(%s, 'g'), '');
        displayUnit = DisplayUnit.s;
    } else if (!isNaN(Number(inputValue))) {
            tempValue = inputValue;
        }
```

Comment: Well, it looks like you need `/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:p|%s)?$/`. Please share your code where your pattern does not work.

Comment: Your regexs don't look like regexs, are you sure the enclosing pair of square brackets isn't a javascript array? Because `/.../` is the javascript regex notation and should be around the regex. `[/^[0-9]*%s$]` either is a character class that would match a character such as `^`  or `$`, or a malformed regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the regex but still i am not  able to enter %s and decimal value

Comment: Your code expects `re` to be an array (you're using `Array.prototype.some` a line further). Since you're trying to handle the three possible formats with a single regex it looks like you should change the code to work with a single regex. If you don't think that's appropriate, you could also try setting `const re=[/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:p|%s)?$/]`, that is Wiktor's regex inside an array

Comment: @Aaron tried with wiktor regex const re=[/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:p|%s)?$/] but still not able to type % and s and it works fine for numbers and p. changing code ? can you guide where exactly you are referring to. Tried with different scenarios still facing the issue

Comment: @ram.v is your regex triggered at every character input and prevent it if it doesn't match? I think that'd explain the problem, the regex matches `%s` but doesn't match `%` alone. Don't mind the code change, it was just about simplifying it to use a single regex rather than an array, but that won't help your problem